# Change a function name to be able to use two or more departments in one model in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I have a models called claims_model and an inbound_model. I am trying to make it so that it can be in one model called departments_model the issue I have is when I change the function name _get_datables_query to something like _get_datables_query_claims it doesn't work. I am a bit lost on what I have to do to achieve this. Also as you can see bellow in my models I am repeating the code over and over again that's why I also want to keep it in one model so as not to repeat. I have 11 total departments but I am only showing two as an example.

claims_model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Claims_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'callin_list';
    var $column = array('Date_Scheduled','Employee_Name','Employee_Number','Time_Reported','Reason','Scheduled_Area','Contact','Comments'); //set column field database for order and search
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','Claims');



        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND. 
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $column[$i] = $item; // set column array variable to order processing
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_claims()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();

    }


    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }


}
```

Inbound_model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Inbound_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'callin_list';
    var $column = array('Date_Scheduled','Employee_Name','Employee_Number','Time_Reported','Reason','Scheduled_Area','Contact','Comments'); //set column field database for order and search
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','INBOUND');



        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND. 
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $column[$i] = $item; // set column array variable to order processing
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_inbound()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();

    }


    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }


}
```

departments_model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Departments_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'callin_list';
    var $column = array('Date_Scheduled','Employee_Name','Employee_Number','Time_Reported','Reason','Scheduled_Area','Contact','Comments'); //set column field database for order and search
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','Claims');



        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND. 
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $column[$i] = $item; // set column array variable to order processing
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_claims()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

// Start of Inbound function section
private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','INBOUND');



        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND. 
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $column[$i] = $item; // set column array variable to order processing
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_inbound()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }


    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();

    }


    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think it would help if you could show what you have tried so far. I recommend showing your `departments_model` and make sure to point out which line of code is misbehaving. Also, describe the symptom of the misbehavior. Both models look exactly the same to me so I am confused, fyi.

Comment: I have not created department_model yet the issue I have is when I change the name _get_datables_query to anything else, because I may not be able to use that twice in the department model to call two different departments.

Comment: I added the departments_model up top when I have two departments in one i get an error

Comment: I know why it is because I am calling _get_datables_query twice so it does not know which one to grab. I am trying to figure how to change the name or create an if statment to get it to work

Comment: I think I figured it out I will post anwere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I moved `$this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','Claims');` and `$this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','Inbound');` to the get function and removed it from the `_get_datatables_query` and it worked here is the new departments_model code.

```
class Departments_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'callin_list';
    var $column = array('Date_Scheduled','Employee_Name','Employee_Number','Time_Reported','Reason','Scheduled_Area','Contact','Comments'); //set column field database for order and search
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);




        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND. 
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $column[$i] = $item; // set column array variable to order processing
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_claims()
    {$this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','Claims');
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_inbound()
    {$this->db->where('Scheduled_Area','Inbound');
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();

    }


    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }


}
```